# Blockquote button interaction with MathJax

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown

Here is a bug which has bitten me a few times now. Suppose I type something like

```
Consider the sequence $s_1 = x_1$, $s_2 = x_1+x_2$, $s_3 = x_1+x_2+x_3$, $s_4 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$, ...
```

Then I decide that I want to put my text in a blockquote environment, so I highlight it and click the little quote icon in the top bar. The editor introduces the markdown

```
> Consider the sequence $s_1 = x_1$, $s_2 = x_1+x_2$, $s_3 =
> x_1+x_2+x_3$, $s_4 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$, ...
```

When MathJax renders that markdown, the `>` symbol is inside a math environment, leading to the incorrect output

> Consider the sequence $s_1 = x_1$, $s_2 = x_1+x_2$, $s_3 =
> > x_1+x_2+x_3$, $s_4 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$, ...

Of course, it is easy to edit the `>` out of the math environment in each case, but it is a little annoying and I figure that, if no one ever reports this, it won't get added to a bug list.

Comment: You may be interested in [this Meta Stack Exchange feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234299).

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks! Agreed, implementing that request would fix this problem and would be easier than making a line wrapper which always breaks lines between math environments.

Comment: I know it's not a fix, but now I simply add myself the single `>` at the beginning of the paragraph (the other ones are unneeded). It's easier than waiting for a bugfix...